# Poor Performance of Parallel Nested Loop in Python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I try to make my code faster so I want the loops to run in parallel. My first question was, how do I implement a parallel loop in Python and which loop do I parallelize?

Here is my code:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time

def compR(R, M, I, l):
    for p in range(ppl):
        for i in range(N):
            R[l][p] += np.dot(M[l][p],I[i])
    return R

level = 20
ppl = 8
x = 70
y = 10
N = 15

M = [[np.random.rand(x,y) for p in range(ppl)] for l in range(level)]
R = [[np.zeros((x,1)) for p in range(ppl)] for l in range(level)]
I = [np.random.rand(y,1) for n in range(N)]

# Seriell
t0 = time.time()
for l in range(level):
    for p in range(ppl):
        for i in range(N):
            R[l][p] += np.dot(M[l][p],I[i])
t1 = time.time()
print(t1-t0)

R = [[np.zeros((x,1)) for p in range(ppl)] for l in range(level)]

num_cores = mp.cpu_count()

# Parallel            
t0 = time.time()
R = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(compR)(R, M, I, l) for l in range(level))            
t1 = time.time()
print(t1-t0)
```

Is the implementation correct? I tried to let the `level` loop run in parallel since normally `level` > `N` > `ppl`. When I run to code for larger numbers of `level` and `x` and `y` the performance of the parallel loop is really bad. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Multiprocessing has overhead starting up and transferring data to and from the processes.  If the parallel work isn't significant enough, this overhead can easily take more time than just doing the work serially in one process.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I don't get it. For a large number of `level` the parallel code is 50 times slower. How can that be. Even with overhead.

Comment: Transferring all that data via interprocess communication is expensive.

Comment: @MarkTolonen What would be a faster alternative?

Comment: @Samuel it's not just the overhead of starting up and transferring, it's that you are using shared state, which needs to be serialized (pickled) and sent across processes. Sharing state in combination with `multiprocessing` is *hard to do correctly* to begin with, and will likely involves a *lot* of overhead.

Comment: @Samuel anyway, your algorithm is well into polynomial time, parallelization, even with no overhead, isn't going to help you a lot. You are looking at `O(ppl*level*d^3)` where `d` stands in for your dot-product, dot product being a quartic-time algorithm (although, that can be improved slightly depending on what implementation you are using, but its still polynomial).

Comment: Running it serially is 50x faster than running in parallel, so run it serially.  If you need faster, multiprocessing isn't the solution.  Look into extensions like `ctypes` or SWIG.  Both have options to work with `numpy` data without a lot of transfer overhead.

Comment: It looks like your entire code would be better optimized if you use pure `numpy.ndarray`s, instead of list-of-numpy arrays, then use `numpy/scipy` matrix-algebra functions, and make sure your numpy/scipy is using a good BLAS implementation backend, which will be parallelized and more finely tuned than you could hope to get with `multiprocessing`.